# React element resets even when its `key` prop is kept the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a web app using React and have come across this weird issue.

As a summary, child elements expressed as an array inside curly braces (eg: `{[<Element />, <Element />]}` are reset when one sibling is added or removed.

My question is whether or not this behavior is expected by React, and if it is, why does it happen?

To illustrate, I came up with two examples. Their code is exactly the same, except that the first declares the elements directly in JSX and the second declares them inside an array (could be generated by `Array.map`):

- [First example (works as expected)](https://jsfiddle.net/jvup1ek9/2/)
- [Second example](https://jsfiddle.net/jvup1ek9/)

`Ticker` is a generic component made up to demonstrate state. `DummyElement` is a generic component with no state whatsoever. `App` is the root component.

In the first example, you can see that, when switching between layouts, that is, when adding or removing the `DummyElement`, the `Tickers` state is preserved. This is the behavior that I would expect, given that the `Tickers` `key` props are kept the same.

In the second example, however, the `Ticker` state is reset whenever you switch between layouts. This is further shown in the console, that logs that the `Tickers` are being mounted and unmounted at each layout change.

Edit:

I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15623) related to the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `react` renders multiple `children` it treats it as an **array** of children, but when the `children` are a **single** child then `react` will treat it as a single element.
In your case is interesting to see that in the first condition the `children` of the `<div className="top">` is an `array` but actually a single child "element":

```
<div className="top">
  {[<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />]}
</div>
```

If we look at it as a react element we will see something roughly like this:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  className: 'top',
  children: [<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />]
}
```

But in the second condition, we have 2 children:

```
<div className="top">
  {[<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />]}
  <DummyElement key="3" />
</div>
```

So basically we have an `array` of children which holds another array of elements **AND** another element.
If we look at it as a react element we will see something roughly like this:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  className: 'top',
  children: [
    [<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />],
    <DummyElement key="3" />
  ]
}
```

So in both cases the `type` of children is an array (by coincidence) but the type of the array members is changing:
In the 1st case the first member of the `array` is the `Ticker` element.
In the 2nd case the first member of the `array` is another `array`

So when react is doing its [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) process it will check the following:

> 1. Two elements of different types will produce different trees.
> 2. The developer can hint at which child elements may be stable across different renders with a key prop.

So your case is falling on the first check:

```
type Ticker -> type Array
```

To proof this point i created the same example as yours but i added an extra element as a child, so `children` will always be a type of `array`, this way we will always get the element as the following:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  className: 'top',
  children: [
    {type: 'div'},
    [<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />],
   /* DummyElement will be added conditionally */
  ]
}
```

Here is a running example (note that i'm preserving the position of the children):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { layout: 1 };
  }

  render() {
    let toRender = null;
    if (this.state.layout == 1) toRender = this._renderLayout1();
    else if (this.state.layout == 2) toRender = this._renderLayout2();
    return toRender;
  }

  _renderLayout1() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="top">
          <div>I'm forcing children as array</div>
          {[<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />]}
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">{this._renderButtons()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderLayout2() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="top">
          <div>I'm forcing children as array</div>
          {[<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />]}
          <DummyElement key="3" />
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">{this._renderButtons()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderButtons() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ layout: 1 })}>2x Ticker</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ layout: 2 })}>
          2x Ticker + DummyElement
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class Ticker extends React.Component {
  // Display seconds from the moment I'm created.

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tickNumber: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(`Mount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ tickNumber: prevState.tickNumber + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log(`Unmount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  render() {
    const displayTick = String(this.state.tickNumber).padStart(4, 0);
    const displayStr = `Ticker "${this.props.name}" - ${displayTick}`;

    return <div className="Ticker">{displayStr}</div>;
  }
}

function DummyElement() {
  return <div className="DummyElement">Dummy element</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.top,
.bottom {
  margin: 1em;
}

.Ticker,
.DummyElement {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Unfortunately we can't provide keys to arrays, so in your case it will always recreate the tree for these arrays, but we can wrap them with an element.

If you can't wrap the array with an additional element (like your first example with a wrapping `div`) you can wrap them with a [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), just make sure you provide the same `key`. Note that a `Fragment` with no `key` is treated as an array, `react` will always "think" it's a new instance host thus will re-create it (and its children).

Here is an example of your second example but with the desired behavior:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {layout : 1};
  }
 
  render() {
   if (this.state.layout == 1)
     return this._renderLayout1();
   else if (this.state.layout == 2)
     return this._renderLayout2();
  }
  
  _renderLayout1() {
   return (
     <div>
        <div className="top">
         <React.Fragment key="1">
           {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
           <Ticker key="2" name="2" />
           ]}
          </React.Fragment>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  _renderLayout2() {
   return (
     <div>
        <div className="top">
         <React.Fragment key="1">
           {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
           <Ticker key="2" name="2" />
           ]}
          </React.Fragment>
            <DummyElement key="3" />
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  _renderButtons() {
   return (
     <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={ () => this.setState({'layout': 1}) }>
          2x Ticker
        </button>
        <button onClick={ () => this.setState({'layout': 2}) }>
          2x Ticker + DummyElement
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class Ticker extends React.Component {
 
  // Display seconds from the moment I'm created.
  
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {tickNumber: 0};
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
   console.log(`Mount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
   this.timerID = setInterval(
     () => {
        this.setState(
          prevState => ({tickNumber: prevState.tickNumber + 1})
        );
      },
      1000
    );
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
   console.log(`Unmount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
   clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  
  render() {
   const displayTick = String(this.state.tickNumber).padStart(4, 0);
    const displayStr = `Ticker "${this.props.name}" - ${displayTick}`;
    
   return (
     <div className="Ticker">
        {displayStr}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

function DummyElement() {
 return (
   <div className="DummyElement">
     Dummy element
   </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
.top,
.bottom {
  margin: 1em;
}

.Ticker,
.DummyElement {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

With that said, I think a better and more readable approach here would be to render everything as is and only conditionally render the `DummyElement`.

```
<div className="top">
  {[<Ticker key="1" name="1" />, <Ticker key="2" name="2" />]}
  {layout === 2 && <DummyElement key="3" />}
</div>
```

But why is this working as expected? I mean in this case will again provide `children` as multiple elements (which `react` will convert to an array) or a single element (which `react` will flatten it to a single element).
Turns out that when we use the `&&` operator `react` will use either the right side (when the condition is `true`) or `null` (when the condition is `false`) and `null` will preserve a "hole" in the `array`. meaning we will always get an `array` of `children`.

Hence we end up with this element:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  className: 'top',
  children: [
    [<Ticker name="1" />, <Ticker name="2" />],
    null || DummyElement
  ]
}
```

Here is a running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { layout: 1 };
  }

  render() {
    return this._renderLayout();
  }

  _renderLayout() {
    const { layout } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="top">
          {[<Ticker key="1" name="1" />, <Ticker key="2" name="2" />]}
          {layout === 2 && <DummyElement key="3" />}
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">{this._renderButtons()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  _renderButtons() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ layout: 1 })}>2x Ticker</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ layout: 2 })}>
          2x Ticker + DummyElement
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class Ticker extends React.Component {
  // Display seconds from the moment I'm created.

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tickNumber: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(`Mount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ tickNumber: prevState.tickNumber + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log(`Unmount Ticker "${this.props.name}"`);
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  render() {
    const displayTick = String(this.state.tickNumber).padStart(4, 0);
    const displayStr = `Ticker "${this.props.name}" - ${displayTick}`;

    return <div className="Ticker">{displayStr}</div>;
  }
}

function DummyElement() {
  return <div className="DummyElement">Dummy element</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.top,
.bottom {
  margin: 1em;
}

.Ticker,
.DummyElement {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this because you've changed the topology (how tags and arrays are nested) of the tree, in sample 2:

Here's a modified version that does not reset state, I preserve array and non-array nodes in the topology:

```
  _renderLayout1() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="top">
          <span>
          {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
            <Ticker key="2" name="2" />          
          ]}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderLayout2() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="top">
          <span>
          {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
            <Ticker key="2" name="2" />          
          ]}
          </span>
          <DummyElement/>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1syr347/

Here's another version that does preserve topology, I've put everything into the array:

```
  _renderLayout1() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="top">
          {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
            <Ticker key="2" name="2" />          
          ]}
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderLayout2() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="top">
          {[
            <Ticker key="1" name="1" />,
            <Ticker key="2" name="2" />,
            <DummyElement key="3"/>
          ]}          
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          {this._renderButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1syr347/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not accepting it yet because I didn't find a place in the docs that tells about topology. However, the fixes work perfectly :)

Comment: I think the closest you get to official docs on the topic would be here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: I don't know... Reading that I am led to believe that the components shouldn't lose their state. I think I will submit an issue to the React github page... Again, thanks for the help!